# nginx: Storing POST data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, rest, nginx, openresty

An nginx server provides a simple REST interface, using a PostgreSQL instance as the backend. The nginx should insert POST data (already in JSON format) into a database table. Unfortunately, the `$request_body` containing the POST data is filled by nginx only on `fastcgi_pass`, `proxy_pass`, …

The [ngx_form_input](https://github.com/calio/form-input-nginx-module) doesn’t help either, as it expects the POST data in key-value format. I tried [ngx_echo](https://github.com/agentzh/echo-nginx-module), but this leads to an internal server error:

```
location ~ "^/api/v1/dummy/$" {
    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    /usr/local/etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    if ($request_method != POST) {
        return 405;
    }

    client_max_body_size    100k;
    client_body_buffer_size 100k;

    echo_read_request_body;

    postgres_pass       postgresql;
    postgres_escape     $json =$request_body;

    postgres_query      POST "INSERT INTO mytable (data) VALUES ('$json')";
    postgres_rewrite    POST changes    201;
    postgres_rewrite    POST no_changes 204;
}
```

It seems that ngx_echo doesn’t work together with ngx_postgres. Are there any other ways to get the request body data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `echo_read_request_body` and `postgres_pass` directives work in content phase.
Only one module would work in this case.

The problem here that nginx is async in its nature.
Nginx may initiate upstream connection **before** full request body is received.

Using OpenResty you can force nginx to read the whole request body by [lua_need_request_body](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_need_request_body).
Take care about `client_body_buffer_size` and `client_max_body_size`.
Include empty `rewrite_by_lua*`.

Another possible solution is to write Lua code, for example within `set_by_lua_block` and read the full request body, keep in mind that it may be buffered into a file, use [ngx.req.get_body_file](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_body_file) to check it.

Comment: Eventually, that’s the only thing that works. I added a `rewrite_by_lua_block` to get the request body with `ngx.req.read_body()` and `ngx.req.get_body_data()`. Thank you for the clarification on why both modules can’t be used at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alexander Altshuler. Nginx does not support capturing request_body in the rewrite phase in which the `postgres_escape` directive is running.

I have modified the ngx_postgres module in my GitHub branch [capture-request-body](https://github.com/Bibop182/ngx_postgres/tree/capture-request-body). But my pull request is unlikely to be accepted.

This branch added the POST request capture feature.
You can save requests to the PostgreSQL database, for example, using such a configuration in this branch

```
location /dlr/sms
{
    allow all;
    postgres_escape_request_body on;
    postgres_pass     database;
    postgres_query    POST      "SELECT table2sms.treat_sms_dlr('$request_body')";
    postgres_rewrite  POST      changes 200;
    postgres_rewrite  POST      no_changes 400;
    postgres_output   value;
}
```